# Is a Single Linear MLP Equivalent to a Random Projection

Tags: machine-learning, st.statistics, ai.artificial-intel

I am just hoping to confirm my hypothesis, that a single MLP (untrained and randomly initialized) can be used for [random projection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/random_projection.html) for dimensionality reduction.

If a random MLP layer with no activation is:

$$Y = X \ W  $$

is there really any difference to the random projection method, especially if its weights are sampled from a distribution with a variance following the [Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/random_projection.html#the-johnson-lindenstrauss-lemma)
 ?

Answer (score 1):

A single MLP layer with no activation function is a linear function, as you already seem to know, and hence trivially equivalent to a projection.  It is equivalent to a random projection if you choose the entries in the matrix randomly from the appropriate distribution.

Normally a single-layer MLP is understood to include an activation.  That is not equivalent to a random projection.

The value of this equivalence is unclear.  If you want a random projection, it seems clearer to simply use a random projection, without needing to introduce a MLP.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm asking because I want to use a random projection in a Tensorflow project, and as far as I can tell, TF doesn't have it yet.   As for an MLP without an activation, I've seen some projects use it for linear operations [(like here for example)](https://github.com/oozdenizci/MMIDimReduction/blob/27b268e1e30d0653073f989eb217203296c0265d/MMIDimReduction.py#L147).